# Fatal Error when using CMU fonts with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, miktex, fontspec

I just tried to re-compile the documentation file for the `russian-babel` package with XeLaTeX. The source file `russianb.dtx` was last modified in January 2017 (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-russian) and then compilation always was successful. But now I got a compilation error. As short investigation revealed that the CMU font is the cause of the problem, as the following example demonstrates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
%\setmainfont{STIX Two}[
%    UprightFont={* Math},
%    %UprightFont={* Text},
%    ItalicFont={* Text Italic},
%    BoldFont={* Text Bold},
%    BoldItalicFont={* Text Bold Italic},
%]
    \setmainfont{CMU Serif}
    \setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
    \setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
    
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

English
\textsf{English}
\texttt{English}

\selectlanguage{russian}
Русский
\textsf{Русский}
\texttt{Русский}
\end{document}
```

Compilation terminated with the following error:

```
dvipdfmx:fatal: This font using the "seac" command for accented characters...

No output PDF file written.
 )
Error 1 (driver return code) generating output;
file test-CMU.pdf may not be valid.
```

So it can be guessed that the error is caused by some recent changes in XeLaTeX executables. Can someone help to solve this problem? Note however that the compilation succeeds if CMU fonts is substituted with STIX Two fonts.

Comment: I can’t reproduce your bug in TeX Live 2020 with babel 3.48. Are you able to update?

Comment: However, one thing you might try is replacing `\setmainfont` with `\babelfont{rm}[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{CMU Serif}`, and so with `\babelfont{sf}` and `\babelfont{tt}`. This will load the correct `Script=` and `Language=`. Probably unrelated to your bug, though.

Comment: I tested with XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992.

Comment: I could not reproduce it with Babel 3.49 and XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992, either.

Comment: @Davislor: I have the same versuiion of XeTeX but MikTeX on Windows 10.

Comment: Nobody yet paid attentiion of the error message. What does it mean?: dvipdfmx:fatal: This font using the "seac" command for accented characters...

Comment: As Ulrike Fischer found out, it means that you have two versions of the font on your system, and XeTeX is erroneously loading the one `fontspec` cannot use.

Answer (score 4):

If you add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` you can see in the log that miktex finds for the typewriter font a type1 font (a `.pfb`):

`/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/cm-unicode/cmuntt.pfb`

and this then fails when trying to typeset the char with the accent.

You can avoid this by setting the font by file name instead of font name (you perhaps will have to set the bold typewriter similar):

```
\setmonofont{cmuntt.otf}
```

Comment: Huh, that doesn’t happen for me. What does `fc-match "CMU Typewriter Text"` show?

Comment: @Davislor are you using miktex on windows?

Comment: No, a full install of TeX Live. Is MikTeX missing a package it needs?

Comment: @Davislor no, it simply finds the wrong font, that's not the first time. One can exclude the type1 font folder from the configuration, but I normally prefer to use file names - more reliable.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yes, on miktex it fails for me too (texlive is ok). That's why I could analyze it and offer a solution.

Comment: See updated Question. XeLaTeX reports that this is DRIVER ERROR.

Comment: yes I know. I get the same error. Did you actually try to replace `\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}` by `\setmonofont{cmuntt.otf}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer/ Yes, I tried and it helps.